# Simplifying repetitive function call in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, refactoring

I'm looking for a way to simplify the following query in Oracle 10g, preferably without resorting to PL/SQL constructs:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE instr(my_col, '<')
    + instr(my_col, '>')
    + instr(my_col, ':')
    + instr(my_col, '"')
    + instr(my_col, '/')
    + instr(my_col, '\')
    + instr(my_col, '|')
    + instr(my_col, '?')
    + instr(my_col, '*')
    + instr(my_col, CHR(0))
    + instr(my_col, CHR(1))
    + instr(my_col, CHR(2))
       -- ...
    + instr(my_col, CHR(31)) > 0
```

The query is looking for characters that are illegal in [Windows paths](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx). Thankfully, I am later appending known legal characters to `my_col`, so I don't have to handle other more complicated cases of illegal names. It can be assumed that `my_col` is not null.

The query works well for my purposes, but I am unhappy with the copy-paste programming I've done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regular expression:

```
where regexp_like(my_col, '[<>:"''/\\|?*\x00\x01\x02]')
```

Or, you might prefer to list the characters that *are* valid.  Something like this:

```
where regexp_like(my_col, '[^a-zA-Z0-9_]')
```